# validate date and time while using seperate controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In my application, I have two seperate boostrap controls one for date and another for time. In javascript, how do I validate if the datetime selected by user is not future datetime?

Comment: what do the values look like?

Comment: like 08/07/2014 2:00 PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should get you in the right direction

```
function checkDate(){
    var selectedDate = new Date("08/07/2014 2:00 PM");
    var now = new Date();

    if(selectedDate < now){
        return true;
    }

}
```

if you problem is getting the values from the control you will need to post some HTML

hope this helps